# SqlCommand VarChar or Int?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering which is the "correct" way of adding parameters to a SQLCommand. It seems to me its best to match the data types. However, is parsing the string to Int better than using the .ToString() method performance wise? Does it go against good practice? SQL server doesn't seem to care. id is of type int in the table.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=@ID";
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

OR

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=@ID";
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
```

Comment: You can use [`AddWithValue` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and skip the data type declaration.

Comment: First methods is best becuase if user pass `string ` , when convert to `int` it throw an exception , but in second method user can pass `string` from query string and you put it in your cluase select and sql return error to can cast string to int . first methods is secure instead of second . its benefid handel error from your code no sql

Comment: I agree, what do you think about tryparse though? would it better to use that then the varchar SqlDbType still?

Comment: By the way, http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @RubensFarias `AddWithValue()` can have unexpected results. [Read here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` type in SQL Server is [mapped](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in `Int32` in CLR side. That's why the "correct" way is adding a parameter which is `SqlDbType.Int`. Period.

> However, is parsing the string to Int better than using the
>   .ToString() method performance wise?

Sending a wrong parameter typed value as a parameter *might* generate more serious problems than a performance. Looks like "performance" is not *even* a real case in your example since you never mentioned any performance issue in your work.

> SQL server doesn't seem to care

But as a developer, *you* should.

Comment: hence the reason I asked the question